# filter dataset column by date(Month/Year)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter, dataset, visual-studio-2015

I have a DataGridView bound to an Access DB.
One of the fields on DB is Date(day) Format.
I want the DataGridView displays only rows within the Month/Year displayd in a DateTimerPicker.
This is the Code I'm using:

Private Sub FrmRelatorio_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'S_CampoDataSet.Servico' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ServicoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.S_CampoDataSet.Servico)


    'Get current month
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim mesactual = currentDate.Month

    'Get DateTimePicker Month
    Dim dataescolhida As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim mesescolhido = dataescolhida.Month

    ServicoBindingSource.Filter = "Util1 = '" & Numero_Utilizador & " ' "
    'ServicoBindingSource.Filter = "Dia = '" & mesescolhido & " ' "
    ServicoBindingSource.Sort = "Dia ASC"
```

I can't find out how to deal with the column Dia, the one containing the Date(Day).
This is what I want in run time:
http://fpessoa.esferinfinita.com/StackOverflow/

Anyone could help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the Type and value of `Numero_Utilizador`?

Comment: In the DB is text. But its use is simply to identify the user.
It's working fine; the filter is doing its job.